# how to fix column not found 1054 unknown column '0' in 'field list' in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I add multiple values to the table using laraval sync method

```
{
    $screenCategoryIds = json_decode($request->get('selected_group_screen_category_ids'));
    $selectedScreenCategories = $this->screenCategorySiteFieldsModel->addSameKeyForElementsInArray($screenCategoryIds,'screen_category_id')
    $siteField->screenCategories()->sync([$selectedScreenCategories]);
}
```

This is the input array:

```
array:3 [
    0 => array:1 ["screen_category_id" => 3]
    1 => array:1 ["screen_category_id" => 6]
    2 => array:1 ["screen_category_id" => 5]
]
```

This is my relationship

```
{
    function screenCategories(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\ScreenCategorySiteFields','site_field_screen_categories','screen_category_site_field_id','id');
    }
}
```

when insert the maltiple values in to table the error is occur " Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list'", how to fix this?

Comment: car you share the content of your `$selectedScreenCategories` ?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel is expecting an array of Ids for your `sync()` method. You can get that easily from your input array using `Arr::pluck()`:

```
$arrayOfIds = Arr::pluck($screenCategoryIds,'screen_category_id');
$siteField->screenCategories()->sync($arrayOfIds);
```